# Recaptcha creates iFrame on page, breaks styling

Tags: html, css, captcha, recaptcha

Recaptcha is adding a "This frame prevents back/forward cache problems in Safari" iFrame to the top of my website (code included below), which is pushing off the styling by 20-30px (approximately).

If I set `display: none;` to the element in Firebug it fixed the problem .

Does anyone know why this element has a height (I have no CSS that applies to iFrames)? Or how to set display: none; on it?

```
<iframe src="about:blank" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; visibility: hidden; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; ">
    This frame prevents back/forward cache problems in Safari.
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try the CSS below:

```
/* ReCaptcha Iframe FIX */
iframe {display:none !important;}
header iframe,
section iframe,
footer iframe,
div iframe { display:inline; }
```

If you don't have any other frames on the site to worry about, a simpler version should suffice:

```
iframe {display:none !important;}
```

Alternatively, you could target all iframes where `src="about:blank"`:

```
iframe[src="about:blank"]{display:none;}
```

Comment: Here are 10 thank you points for solving my same problem on a heart beat! =P

Comment: +1, And this is the kind of stuff that just drives a man insane!

Comment: THANK YOU for this. This was really driving me nuts. Side note: the reCAPTCHA API is pretty miserable... whoever designed that makes me want to die.

Answer (score 24):

```
iframe[src="about:blank"]{display:none;}
```

This matches all iframes with the "src" attribute of "about:blank".

Comment: from @OwenMelbourne: should have been src not href for iframes

Answer (score 5):

This seems simpler and more accurate:

```
body > iframe { display:none !important; }
```