# reCAPTCHA changing the height of my content by about -20px

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

Without reCAPTCHA, my page looks like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXufS/)):

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="content_wrap">
    <div class="left_container">
    </div>

    <div class="right_container">
        <div style="background-color: blue; margin:0px; height: 1500px;">
        <!--RECAPTCHA WOULD GO HERE-->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body,html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

div.content_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

div.left_container {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 220px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

div.right_container {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

​

With reCAPTCHA (in the blue area) the height of the entire page's content is reduced by ~20px at the bottom with a visible strip of white space.

Has anyone had problems with reCAPTCHA altering elements of their layout?

Comment: reCAPTCHA is normally very reliable. Can you link to where you have an actual webpage with the reCAPTCHA installed, as (unless anyone knows how) you can get a fully fledged version working on jsfiddle. If you can't I will look into it in an hour or two when i am at a pc if no one beats me to it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to [replicate your issue](http://jsfiddle.net/BXufS/5/) based on [this reCAPTCHA jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hqv27/).

It looks like reCAPTCHA causes an empty `iframe` to be appended to the bottom of the page.

```
<iframe src="about:blank" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; visibility: hidden; border: none;">
    This frame prevents back/forward cache problems in Safari.
</iframe>
```

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=This%20frame%20prevents%20back/forward%20cache%20problems%20in%20Safari.) on the message in the `iframe` results in a lot of discussion on the issue.

And here's a solution found on SO: [Recaptcha creates iFrame on page, breaks styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155645/recaptcha-creates-iframe-on-page-breaks-styling)

> Try the CSS below:
>
> ```
> /* ReCaptcha Iframe FIX */
> iframe {display:none !important;}
> header iframe,
> section iframe,
> footer iframe,
> div iframe { display:inline; }
> ```
>
> If you don't have any other frames on the site to worry about, a
>   simpler version should suffice:
>
> ```
> iframe {display:none !important;}
> ```

Finally, here's the jsfiddle with the solution implemented: http://jsfiddle.net/BXufS/7/.

Answer (score 3):

I fix that problem by targeting iframe `src` attribute in CSS

```
<iframe src="about:blank" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; visibility: hidden; border: none;"></iframe>

iframe[src="about:blank"] { display: none; }
```

of course I have no other iframes with `about:blank` source ;)